# Flutter ModalBottomSheet remove white lines

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I can't seem to find a good way to remove these small white lines, changed the container color to fit with the ModalBottomSheet default background color.

[image]

Here is a part of code:

```
void mountainModalBottomSheet(context){
  showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (BuildContext bc){
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xff757575),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.60,
      child:Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 225,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(38),
                topRight: Radius.circular(38),
              ),
              image:DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage('https://hotelvilatina.hr/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/sljeme.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill),
            ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

You can use `shape` property but you need to make sure of providing `clipBehavior:hardEdge`

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, // or hardEdge must 
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(38),
        topRight: Radius.circular(38),
      ),
    ),
    context: context,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    builder: (c) {
      return Container();
    });
```

Wrap your `Container` with `ClipRRect` widget

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, // make sure of it
    builder: (c) {
      return ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(38),
            topRight: Radius.circular(38),
          ),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
          ));
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [ClipRRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "shape" property of showModalBottomSheet to give a radius to your bottom sheet. In this way, your bottom sheet has its own radiuses and you will no longer see your white lines.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
  ),
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  ...
);
```